# Bad title when creating new chat room

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

When creating a new chat room, the "This room might already exist" page has a `<title>` with an unprocessed code snippet:

[image: Screenshot of the bug]

Comment: This looks to be server side, but just in case: Repro'd on WinXP - Chrome 13.0.782.112 beta-m, IE 8, FF 5.0.1.

Comment: I `<%: Current.balpha.Reaction.AsVerb() %>` that this should be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A leftover from back when we converted most of our view from the WebForms view engine to Razor. Fixed in the next chat build.